# make text a link in svg

Tags: d3.js, svg, hyperlink

I'm using     d3 to draw a chart (I'm using thix example: https://gist.github.com/keiranlovett/8766741). I need to add a link. I'm adding text and I'm trying to make it a link, but it's not appearing as a link (I'm using IE 11):

```
svg.append("g") //without doing this, impossible to put grid lines behind text  

     .attr({
            xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
            xlink: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
            width: 100,
            height: 300
        })
     .attr({ "xlink:href": "#" })
     .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
            //alert('aaa');
            d3.select(this)
                .attr({ "xlink:href": "http://example.com/" + "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" });
        })
     .selectAll("text")

     .data(tasks)
     .enter()
     .append("text")

     .text(function (d) {
         if (ammendmentsLinks.indexOf(d.contract) < 0) {
             ammendmentsLinks = ammendmentsLinks + d.contract + ";";
             return d.contract;
             //return "";
         }
         else {
             return "";
         }
     })
     .attr("x", 20)
     .attr("y", function (d, i) {
         return i * 20;
     })
     .attr("font-size", 11)
     .attr("text-anchor", "start")
     .attr("text-height", 14)
     .on("click", function (d) {
         return click(d.contract);
     });
```

I also added some lines of code from http://jsfiddle.net/christopheviau/B9zcF/ to make the text a link but it's not working.

How to make my text a link?

Comment: You need to wrap the `<text>` element in an `<a>` element.

Comment: could you please take my code and update it? I'm new to svg, I didn't had time to look over documentation and I neeed to finish a task to make this chart and it's hard for me to make it work. Thanks

Comment: @RobertLongson indeed, this worked (I wasn't aware that a element from jsfiddle was <a> from html). Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

```
d3.select(this)
            .attr({ "xlink:href": "http://example.com/" + "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" });
```

to

```
d3.select(this)
            .wrap("<a xlink:href \"http://example.com/\"></a>")
            .text("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
```

and make sure the `<svg>` tag has `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` specified.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good solution too:

```
  d3.select(this)
              .text(d)
              .on("click", function() { window.open("https://www.random.com/" + d ); });
```

Comment: d3 version 5 works with this. "wrap is not a function" happens for the other answer